# Change coding in java script function

Tags: javascript

I have never seen it, but is there a way to modify the existing java script function through the code? Something similar to "ALTER PROCEDURE..." statement in SQL Server?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless it was declared using `const`, you can simply reassign it.

Answer (score 6):

You can *replace* any function in Javascript simply by assigning a new function to it, they're merely object properties or simple variables:

```
Math.max = function () {
    return Math.random();  // har har har
};
```

You cannot trivially "reach into" a function and change something about its internals though, no. Or at least, that would be pretty insane.

Comment: `// har har har`  It wasn't you who wrote our accounts software was it. :)

Comment: No, for accounts software I obviously include a `skimFractionOfTransaction(transaction, deceze)`.